# ld: framework not found ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Really not sure what to do. I've tried adding `"ObjC"` to `Other Linker Flags`, tried to remove it. Re-installed CocoaPods in the project several times, cleaned the project and stuff. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Hi, are you able to resolve this issue ? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. Just modify "Other Linker flags". 
It have to be $(inherited) and -ObjC only in **both debug and release**.

Comment: I do have both in "Other Linker flags". Still facing the issue. I also tried to update pods. But dint help.